# AngularJS: Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] with jsfiddle

Tags: angularjs, jsfiddle

Why is this simple script throwing a Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] in the console?

```
<script>
angular.module('HelloWorldApp', []);
angular.module('HelloWorldApp').controller('HelloWorldController', function($scope) {
       $scope.greeting = "Hello World";
});
</script>
<div ng-app="HelloWorldApp">
    <div ng-controller="HelloWorldController">
        <h1>{{greeting}}</h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Lccfcrwm/

Comment: the fiddle. not add angular.js script

Comment: Sorry, can you rephrase? I'm not sure I understand?

Comment: sorry, i mean, i dont see any problem with your configuration, but in the fiddle i dont see where is the script injectected in the html.

Comment: The angular.min.js is injected as an external resource... the script above is just in the javascript frame. I'm not sure what you mean by injecting the script into the html.

Comment: i dont konw how fiddles work. i copy your code and work fine in plknr.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Got your fiddle working, actually in the javascript pane you need to select angular 1.x version and it will start working

here is the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/2xxf507e/

```
 angular.module('HelloWorldApp', []);
 angular.module('HelloWorldApp').controller('HelloWorldController', function($scope) {
       $scope.greeting = "Hello World";
});
```

[image: Setting Image]

and the setting image

Comment: Thanks, I noticed I got the same error with AngularJS 1.4.8 selected, but it worked once I selected load type of 'No wrap - in <body>'. I do not understand what I did wrong in the first place, however... I assume you cannot add angular as an external resource without this option? Shouldn't jsfiddle mention that?

Answer (score 2):

You have to add this in HTML:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
```

This is a simple example :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <p>{{greeting}}</p>
</div>

<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.greeting = "Hello";

});
</script>



</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yes, that worked. I incorrectly assumed that adding angular as an external resource would work the same as a <script src='[external resource]'></script>.